# Space between Dots in a TabLayout

Tags: java, android

I have the following Fragment with a TabLayout with 2 Tabs. Each Tab is filled with one dot to represent the page inside the viewpager.

How can I set space / padding / margin between the 2 Tabs with the dots inside?

I tried several things out, but nothing works for me.

Thanks for your help :)

fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

       <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/pager"
         />

       <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tabDots"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="7.5dp"
           app:tabBackground="@drawable/dot_selector"
           app:tabGravity="center"
           app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
           app:tabMaxWidth="7.5dp"
           />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

dot_selector.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/dot_default" />
</selector>
```

dot_selected.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:useLevel="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorBlack"/>
    <corners android:radius="1000dp"/>
</shape>
```

dot_default.xml  :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:useLevel="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorGrey"/>
    <corners android:radius="1000dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use padding like:

```
app:tabPaddingStart="10dp"
app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
```

Comment: I tried but the dots are still sticking together. Do you know a different way to fix this ?

Comment: Did you added gravity and mode of TabLayout like app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill" and app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false" ? . Also update your support libary version in 28. It works for me.

Comment: @NilsKyuubi, could you please address the right solution if it serves perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You are Using

```
       <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabDots"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="7.5dp"
       app:tabBackground="@drawable/dot_selector"
       app:tabGravity="center"
       app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       app:tabMaxWidth="7.5dp"              //here is the problem
       />
```

Increase tabMaxWidth to have desired space between dots.